# How to prevent the input of a specfic value into a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to prevent the input of a specific value (text saying "latest") in a column but the code I've got doesn't seem to be functioning, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
Private Sub RevisionInput()
    Dim Revision As Range
    Dim Revisioncell As Range
    Set Revision = Range("M3:M500")
    For Each Revisioncell In Revision
    If Revisioncell Like "Latest" Or Revsioncell Like "LATEST" Or Revisioncell Like "latest" Then


MsgBox "Please input correct revision or if one is not available," & _
" Please type 'To be confirmed'"
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Undo
Application.EnableEvents = True

Else
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA is unnecessary. Use data validation.

Comment: Looks to me like you have a missing `End If` and `Next Revisioncell` after the Else statement. In fact you could remove the Else statement as there is nothing to do in that case. Also, I would do `If Lcase(Revisioncell) = "latest"` to avoid having to check different cases. You don't need to use `like` unless you are checking for partial content of a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without VBA. Under the Data tab on the ribbon chose Data Validation, then choose custom from the drop down and set the formula to (replace `M3` with the first cell in your selection):

```
=M3<>"latest"
```

Comment: Oh awesome thanks - don't need the VBA. Although I would still be interested to see how to solve it using VBA

Comment: @AaronGretton Try do what I have described above with the macro recorder turn on...

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Data validation is *the* single simplest and most idiomatic way to prevent invalid user input in a cell. How to programmatically implement data validation is well documented already, both here and literally everywhere on the Internet. Search, you'll find.

Comment: @MatsMug I agree this looks like a good approach. It also handles upper/lower/mixed case text. You can also enter your own validation error message such as 'You cannot enter "Latest" here'